# Inheriting __init_subclass__-parameters

Tags: python-3.x

Let's say I have a class that requires some arguments via `__init_subclass__`:

```py
class AbstractCar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = self.engine_class()

    def __init_subclass__(cls, *, engine_class, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.engine_class = engine_class

class I4Engine:
    pass
class V6Engine:
    pass

class Compact(AbstractCar, engine_class=I4Engine):
    pass
class SUV(AbstractCar, engine_class=V6Engine):
    pass
```

Now I want to derive another class from one of those derived classes:

```py
class RedCompact(Compact):
    pass
```

The above does not work, because it expects me to re-provide the `engine_class` parameter. **Now, I understand perfectly, why that happens**. It is because the `Compact` inherits `__init_subclass__` from `AbstractCar`, which is then called when `RedCompact` inherits from `Compact` and is subsequently missing the expected argument.

I find this behavior rather non-intuitive. After all, `Compact` specifies all the required arguments for `AbstractClass` and should be usable as a fully realized class. *Am I completely wrong to expect this behavior? Is there some other mechanism that allows me to achieve this kind of behavior?*

I already have two solutions but I find both lacking. The first one adds a new `__init_subclass__` to `Compact`:

```py
class Compact(AbstractCar, engine_class=I4Engine):
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(engine_class=I4Engine, **kwargs)
```

This works but it shifts responsibility for the correct working of the `AbstractCar` class from the writer of that class to the user. Also, it violates DRY as the engine specification is now in two places that must be kept in sync.

My second solution overrides `__init_subclass__` in derived classes:

```py
class AbstractCar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = self.engine_class()

    def __init_subclass__(cls, * , engine_class, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.engine_class=engine_class
        @classmethod
        def evil_black_magic(cls, **kwargs):
            AbstractCar.__init_subclass__(engine_class=engine_class, **kwargs) 
        if '__init_subclass__' not in cls.__dict__:        
            cls.__init_subclass__ = evil_black_magic
```

While this works fine for now, it is purest black magic and bound to cause trouble down the road. I feel like this cannot be the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed—the way this works in Python is counter-intuitive—I agree with you on your reasoning.

The way to go to fix it is to have some logic in the metaclass. Which is a pity, since avoiding the need for metaclasses is exactly what `__init_subclass__` was created for.

Even with metaclasses it would not be an easy thing—one would have to annotate the parameters given to `__init_subclass__` somewhere in the class hierarchy, and then insert those back when creating new subclasses.

On second thought, that can work from within `__init_subclass__` itself. That is: when `__init_subclass__` "perceives" it did not receive a parameter that should have been mandatory, it checks for it in the classes in the mro (mro "method resolution order"—a sequence with all base classes, in order).
In this specific case, it can just check for the attribute itself—if it is already defined for at least one class in the mro, just leave it as is, otherwise raises.

If the code in `__init_subclass__` should do something more complex than simply annotating the parameter as passed, then, besides that, the parameter should be stored in an attribute in the new class, so that the same check can be performed downstream.

In short, for your code:

```
class AbstractCar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = self.engine_class()

    def __init_subclass__(cls, *, engine_class=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        if engine_class:
            cls.engine_class = engine_class
            return
        for base in cls.__mro__[1:]:
            if getattr(base, "engine_class", False):
                 return
        raise TypeError("parameter 'engine_class' must be supplied as a class named argument")
```

I think this is a nice solution.  It could be made more general with a decorator meant specifically for `__init_subclass__` that could store the parameters in a named class attribute and perform this check automatically.

(I wrote the code for such a decorator, but having all the corner cases for named and unamed parameters, even using the `inspect` model can make things ugly)